# Solidity you can do bytes32(0) but can not do bytes32(1), why is that?

Tags: solidity

The title is very clear. When I do bytes32(1), it gives me an error about can not cast constant_1 to bytes32. But I can do it on zero. I am scare because I am using bytes32(0) on my contract and I affraid that something will go wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Solidity you can do bytes32(0) but can not do bytes32(1), why is that?

This syntax is disallowed since solidity [0.5.0](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/develop/Changelog.md#050-2018-11-13) :

> Type System: Disallow explicit and implicit conversions from decimal
> literals to bytesXX types.

The "explanation" is in the [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/types.html#id20) :

> Decimal number literals cannot be implicitly converted to fixed-size
> byte arrays. Hexadecimal number literals can be, but only if the
> number of hex digits exactly fits the size of the bytes type. As an
> exception both decimal and hexadecimal literals which have a value of
> zero can be converted to any fixed-size bytes type

So as you can see, `bytes32(0)` is perfectly fine (because the internal representation of a `bytes32` and `uint256` are the same for value 0). For any other value there is some ambiguity (in my opinion) as `bytesX` pads to the right while `intX` / `uintX` pads to the left, hence you either use an explicit conversion or fully specify your initialization litteral :

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Example {

  function test() public view returns (bytes32, bytes32, bytes32) {
    // Not allowed : do you mean 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 <- left padding
    //                        or 0x1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 <- right padding
    // bytes32 a = bytes32(0x1);

    // Allowed : Fully specified : left padding
    bytes32 a = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001;

    // Allowed : Fully specified : right padding
    bytes32 b = 0x1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;

    // Allowed : Explicit conversion : left padding
    bytes32 c = bytes32(uint256(1));

    return (a, b, c);
  }
}
```

It is unclear why you are using decimal litterals to initialize `bytes32` but keep in mind that this is not what they are for. They are byte arrays, not numerical values.

Comment: Well, I wanted to use bytes32(0) to represent a null value of bytes32 type, something like `if (merkleRoot == bytes32(0) revert;`, I don't have a specific use case for bytes32(1), I just discovered that I could not do that, so I was wondering why is that and I affraid that when the contract on the mainnet something will happen for that line `bytes32(0)`. And I greatly appreciate your help